# Pyqt5 + Matplotlib Incompatability?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

Im trying to display a graph with data generated from a Gui using matplotlib.
It does not work if I import `QFileDialog` and try to do `plt.show(block=False)`. `plt.show()` works but naturally, blocks further commands

Ive done fresh pip installs of both pyqt5 and matplotlib in a venv and here is some code to reproduce:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

a=[1,2,3]
plt.plot(a)
plt.show(block=False).
```

Can someone help me get around this?
Will this also happen if I try to convert to pyside2?

Answer (score 0):

To solve, use matplotlib's Qt backend:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```